# Is Visual Studio 2003 still available/supported

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

Pretty much what the title says really.

We have some code that is .NET 1.1 based and no real desire to up-convert it.  However, we are looking to add developers to the team and they will need copies of Visual Studio.

My understanding is that they will need VS 2003 - as this is the only IDE that supports .NET 1.1 but I am wondering if we are still able to purchase it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio 2003 is still available to download for MSDN subscribers.

The EULA for Visual Studio includes a 'downgrade' clause, which appears, IMNAL, to allow you to buy Visual Studio 2008 and then install 2003 under the same license.

> DOWNGRADE. You may install and use
>   this version and an earlier version of
>   the software at the same time. This
>   agreement applies to your use of the
>   earlier version. If the earlier
>   version includes different components,
>   any terms for those components in the
>   agreement that comes with the earlier
>   version apply to your use of them.
>   Microsoft is not obligated to supply
>   earlier versions to you.

Answer (score 8):

You can build 1.1 projects in Visual Studio 2005:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingNET11ProjectsUsingVisualStudio2005.aspx

The MSBuild Everett Environment (MSBEE) has been announced, and soon this will be a (reasonably) supported scenario and we'll all be able to build both 1.1 and 2.0 versions of .NET code on Visual Studio 2005.

Also read this post about this issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/clichten/archive/2005/11/08/490541.aspx

And also:

[MSBuild Extras](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=MSBee) – Toolkit for .NET 1.1 “MSBee” is an addition to MSBuild that allows developers to build managed applications using Visual Studio 2005 projects that target .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 2):

Mainstream support for VS2003 ends in October of this year:

http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=Visual+Studio

Extended support (whatever that means) is still available for quite some time.

Comment: Mainstream support for the framework (1.1) ends at the same time

Comment: Differences between mainstream vs extended support are explained here: http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Espo's link, look into [MSBee](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBee), an enhancements kit for MSBuild to better support .NET Framework 1.1.

It seems you can even [use .NET 1.1 with Visual Studio 2008](http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2008/08/22/working-with-net-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008-and-team-server.aspx), though, so you should have no problem.

That said, I'd be interested in hearing what made you choose against upgrading.

Comment: The decision not to upgrade is because of lack of (programmer) resources.  It works, and only needs minimal support so we don't want to touch it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Supported:  Yes
Available:  Not through normal channels.  You might still find a boxed copy on Amazon or somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 1.1 code can be imported in VS 2005, as .NET 2.0 is backward compatible with .NET 1.1.

You'll probably have to convert the project, but it should still run in VS 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that vs2003 looses support in october